# How do I remove this folder from my github?

Tags: github

I'm a beginner to using github and I accidentally added this folder to my github but I cannot find a way to remove this please help.

I tried deleting this folder from my main folder and redoing my git pull and push and in the terminal it said that this file as already been removed. But once I pushed my file again the files that needed to be updated were updated but the folder is still on my github repo.

Comment: Is it a folder that has sensitive data that you didn't mean to push to GitHub? Because if so, deleting it and then doing a push won't remove it. It'll still be in the git history. If it's an urgent matter of deleting sensitive data then delete the repository from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`git rm -r <folder>`

`git commit -m "remove folder"`

`git push`

The changes will only be saved when you run the commit command

Comment: It should be noted that this just hides the folder going forward. Its contents will still be accessible to anyone who has access to the repo.